# What is a best way to use socket connection in application?

Tags: android

My application(online game) have to use socket connection in many activity and it should maintain a connection all the time. Every activity have to receive message from socket in realtime and activity sometimes sent message to socket. I tried to pass socket from one activity to others but it fail. I tried to use service but I can't sent or receive message from the service, just see it from system.out.println() in a log cat. Is there a best way or common way that games developer use? Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread (or check periodically in the main program) to receive & send the messages, as well as encode/decode them, and pass only the content of the messages to the activities, not the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use socket is the following combination
1. **Celery**(python)
2. **Rabbitmq**(python)
And rabbitmq is basically implementes on sockets.
Celery basically uses a mechanism to distribute work across threads or machines.
You can use rabbitmq queue to  input a unit of work called a task. Dedicated worker processes written in celery python constantly monitor task queues for new work to perform.

Celery communicates via messages, usually using a broker to mediate between clients and workers. To initiate a task the client adds a message to the queue, the broker then delivers that message to a worker.

And worker do whatever is needed to get the work done.

You can refer the docs of celery and rabbitmq 
1. [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html)
2. [Rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html)